# twitter bootstrap layout strange behaviour

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, layout, twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen

I have a strange behaviour in screen layout, I do not understand the possible cause:( 
I have a vertical grey line on the left and the right of the screen,

See screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

BTW, I developed using Rails 3 and using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2

In facts I do not foresee / I do not want these lines ... I presume it could be some CSS setting (on my one customization css code...), sorry for my ignorance there,

watching the shot here do suggest you something about why the grey vertical line on the left marging and the right margin of the screen layout ?

thanks a lot 
giorgio

[scss customization file used: http://solyaris4.altervista.org/custom.css.scss](http://solyaris4.altervista.org/custom.css.scss)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any CSS and HTML code it is pretty difficult to tell.

But since it looks like you are using the Google Chrome browser, hover over the grey stripe with your mouse, right-click and select Inspect Element.  You can then review the html and css code related to what you are looking at.  You can also open the Chrome dev console at any time by hitting the CTRL-SHIFT-i keys.

Comment: thanks Geoff. I edited my original post with a link to the CSS (scss) file I used to customize bootstrap. BTW, the screenshot above come from Forefox. White Chrom I have the same effect of that grey stripe...

Comment: I would need the html as well to see your layout and usage of the CSS.  Do you have a barebones, no content page that demonstrates the problem?  A working sample in http://jsfiddle.net/ would be great.